# Как лучше расставить знаки в двух предложениях (фантастика)?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-неоднородные-определения

**Вот текст** (мое творчество, фантастика-сказка):

*Уже близился вечер, а на скамейке (?) совершенно одна(?)  сидела маленькая **девочка** с голубыми глазами(?) хорошенькая(?) как кукла. И рядом(?)  черная(?), лохматая **собака**(?)  отнюдь не маленькая.*

У меня получилось много **запятых.** Как бы иначе расставить знаки?  (Желательно с объяснением.)

**Тема:** обособление определений, однородные определения и др.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать так:

Уже близился вечер, а на скамейке, совершенно одна, сидела маленькая девочка с голубыми глазами. Хорошенькая, как кукла. И рядом — черная лохматая собака, отнюдь не маленькая.

*Все происшедшее ночью показалось ей тяжелым сном, и, хотя при дневном свете деревья и кусты уже не были такими страшными, девочка никак не могла себе представить, что это она ночью, **совершенно одна,** бегала на утес* (Валентина Осеева. Динка).

*Да, точно, вот она сидит, **хорошенькая, как картинка*** (Александра Маринина. За все надо платить).

*И автоинспекторы понимали стремительный бег грузовика: только что мимо них проскочила с невероятной скоростью девочка-робот и **черная лохматая собака*** (Евгений Велтистов. Новые приключения Электроника).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, за внимание к ответу. Все хорошо, и парцелляция мне в принципе нравится, но всегда ли ее можно применить? Здесь не хотелось бу делить текст на очень короткие фразы, структура с чередованием (длинное и короткое) выглядит интереснее. И важный момент с обособлением. "С голубыми глазами" входит в основное сообщение (определяющий признак), а этот признак уточняющий, как мне кажется (запятая нужна). Как бы это место отредактировать.

Comment: И еще с этой собакой, можно ли считать определения неоднородными в такой последовательности признаков.  В литературе есть такой пример (спасибо!) , но точно ли это правильно?

Comment: 1. *"С голубыми глазами" входит в основное сообщение (определяющий признак), а этот признак уточняющий, как мне кажется (запятая нужна). Как бы это место отредактировать.* Простите, не поняла — о каком *этом признаке* идет речь? О какой запятой? 2. Черный лохматый (пес, кобель, собака) в Нацкорпусе в подавляющем большинстве пишется без обособления. Но думаю, что в определенном контексте (например, при упоминании перед этим пятнистой, светлой или белой, или лысой, или гладкошерстной животины) обособление, конечно же, возможно.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо вам за помощь.